# onMoveGroup example for vis.js

Tags: javascript, angularjs, vis.js

I have a web app using vis.js and eventhough my method for onMove works the onMoveGroup is not working and I can't find any examples for this online.

My code is like this:

```
        onMove: function (item, callback) {
            console.log("onMove", item, callback)
        },
        onMoveGroup: function (item, callback) {
            console.log("onMoveGroup", item, callback)
        },
```

this is how the begining of my timeline options are:

```
  var timelineOptions = {
                height: "100%",
                stack: false,
                hiddenDates: [],
                orientation: 'top',
                selectable: true,
                zoomable: true,
                multiselect: true,
                multiselectPerGroup: true,
                zoomKey: 'ctrlKey',
                //throttleRedraw: 250,
                start: moment.preprocessDate().startOf('week').subtract(6, 'days'),
                end: moment.preprocessDate().add(userTimelineRange, 'days'),
                timeAxis: {scale: 'weekday', step: 1},
                format: {
                    minorLabels: {
                        'weekday': 'DD [(][K][W]W[)]',
                        'day': 'DD [(][K][W]W[)]'
                    }
                },
                showMajorLabels: true,
                groupOrder: function (a, b) {
                    return a.order - b.order;
                },
                editable: {
                   //...
                },
```

Answer (score 1):

See the timeline [configuration](http://visjs.org/docs/timeline/#Configuration_Options) option `groupEditable`, which is false by default. From the options you posted, it appears you're not enabling this feature.